# gta_sa has stopped working

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-games

[image]

Please help to fix this problem. It is occurred when running GTA-SanAndreas game.

Answer (score 1):

According to this entry, the game works only for some users:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Name=GTA%20San%20Andreas&vendor=Rockstar%20Games&Locale=1033&ModelOrVersion=1&BreadCrumbPath=GTA%20San%20Andreas&Type=Software&tempOsid=win8

Check the linked MS community posts. 1 post tells, that you have to update DirectX. Please try this.